# Trying to change custom dialog Background color

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Ok so I am trying change my background of my dialog box from white to a dark blue. However when I long press on one of the grid elements the dialog box looks like this:

[image: How it looks]

I am trying to make it look something like this (this is a photoshop):

[image: PhotoShop of how I want it to look like]

Here is snipet of my XML code for the edit dialog

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:padding="16dp"
android:background="@color/customBG">
```

Java code for custom dialog

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_game_dialog,null);

    editTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
    editTitle.setText(currentTitle);
    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_image_dialog);
    imageView.setImageResource(currentImage);
    changeImageBt = view.findViewById(R.id.change_image);

    changeImageBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

        }
    });

    builder.setView(view).setTitle("Edit game")
            .setPositiveButton("Apply Changes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                    String title = editTitle.getText().toString();
                    int image = R.drawable.blank; //PLACE HOLDER CODE
                    editGameDialogListener.applyChanges(pos,title,image);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {

                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use Dialog instead of AlertDialog.
Alert Dialog has its own Title and Button.

With Dialog you will have the benefit of defining your Title and Buttons.

Create a Layout as your design needs and set it in Dialog.

```
class ABC(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_layout)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your dialog, you can pass theme as a second param

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

and set the custom theme to override anything you need. For background color something like this should work:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@color/customBG</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tried that but I now have somthing that looks like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_6QjzAeSvhmKPLC-5gK7QRj42gedfcBS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can also try setting back color for `android:windowBackground` or `android:backgroundTint` in theme instead of `android:background`